# jquery plugin - accessing the dom with elem

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, element, css-selectors

So I am writing my first jquery plugin for a gallery. The problem I am having is accessing the dom elements that are related to the controls I am pressing.

```
init: function(options, elem) {
var self = this;
arrows = $(elem).find('.gallery-nav-bar  .widget.arrow');
console.log(arrows);
```

how to I combine selectors with objects?

$(elem '.arrow'); //I know this does not work

note:

$('.arrow', elem) works a treat, like this much better than find. I take it I can also use this syntax with this - $('#selector', this) ? Is there any documentation for this type of selection?

Comment: are you trying to find `$(elem)` with class `arrow`?

Comment: no I am trying to find .arrow within the current element

Comment: Then `$(elem).find('.arrow')` or `$('.arrow', elem)` should work.